# Get total row count and first 10 rows from table in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a mysql query such that I can retreieve the first 10 rows of a table and get the total row count in the same query.

i.e. combine

```
SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10; // Get First 10 Rows
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM myTable // Total Row Count
```

in the same query.

Since I'm using PHP, technically I could execute :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Then use count() to get total row count and array_slice to get first 10 array elements.

But that doesn't sound very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM myTable LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

It's not exactly in one query, but the second query is always the same and it won't have to execute the complete previous query again, which is good if it is a complex query.

It's the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` clause in the first query that causes the total number of records to be calculated as if the limit wasn't added.

Comment: SELECT FOUND_ROWS() will retrive the total row count of the previous query, if executed after a SELECT Blahblah LIMIT 10 will be always lesser or equal than 10

Comment: No it won't, `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the select causes the total number of rows to be calculated as if the `LIMIT` wasn't there. Read the docs, this is a great feature, especially for paging and such.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, sorry, didn't see the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),* as cnt FROM myTable group by (anyROW) limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT myTable.*, count(*) as count from myTable LIMIT 10;`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM TheTable) as ct, TheTable.* FROM TheTable limit 10;
```

Comment: That would work in this simple example, but in practise, you'll often select using more conditions, in which case you have to repeat the query to get the total. Even this simple query is already quite more complex.